# How to write non display character (ESC) to screen in COBOL

Tags: cobol

A client of ours needs to write an ESC sequence to a terminal from a COBOL program.  He knows how to write regular text, but the question is how to add an HEX 1B (ESC) to that.

My knowledge of COBOL is rather rusty (30 years past), so I'm really not sure how this is done (beyond a bit of speculation).

So, for sake of a simple example, how do you create a field that contains two bytes, an ESC (1B) and a comma that can be used to do output?

Comment: An ordinary VALUE clause can, since the 1985 Standard, use a hexadecimal literal. Prefixed or post-fixed by X, using either quotes or apostrophes. `VALUE X'1B'.` for instance. Can be used anywhere an alpha-numeric literal can be used.

Comment: I see.  It seems my client didn't know that.  But now it turns out that control  characters get somehow suppressed or translated (this is a cobol program running on suse linux through a terminal manager).  I guess this has to do with EBCDIC and I first have to understand what's being wrapped around it.

Comment: You perhaps can explain the setup more, like where EBCDIC comes into it. Why do they need these characters?